# Wicket Testing behaviour

Tags: java, junit, wicket

I'm trying to the test a method is called when a text field is updated. However it can't seem to get it to work as it doesn't seem to trigger the onUpdate event.

It seems to be hitting the onError event due to trying to convert a null value.

```
org.apache.wicket.util.convert.ConversionException: Method [public long uk.co.cdl.strata.web.client.accounts.payment.PostUnderwriterTransactionContext.getNettAmount()]. Can't convert null value to a primitive class: long for setting it on uk.co.cdl.strata.web.client.accounts.payment.PostUnderwriterTransactionContext@67770b37
```

So it looks like as it has no value set its getting an error. But I'm not sure how to set its value before running the test.

My test case is

```
    @Test
    public void shouldUseDefaultCaseForUpdatingAmount() {
        // Given
        setContext(1);
        setNettRated();
        testSubject = createAndStartPanel();

        // When
        tester.executeAjaxEvent(NETT_AMOUNT_ID, "change");

        // Then
        verify(mockNettViewController, times(1)).updateAmount(any());
    }
```

Here is how I'm setting the text field. I never seems to trigger the onUpdate event.

```
    protected TextField<Float> createNettAmountTextField(String id, String key) {
        CurrencyTextField currencyTextField = CurrencyTextField.createPenceCurrencyQuestion(id, new PropertyModel<Long>(getModel(), key));
        currencyTextField.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        currencyTextField.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
        currencyTextField.setVisible(isTransactionsTypeChoiceAvailable());
        if (amountInputValidator != null) {
            currencyTextField.add(amountInputValidator);
        }
        currencyTextField.add(new StopAutomaticValidationBehaviour());
        currencyTextField.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("change") {
            @Override
            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                updateValue(id);
                redrawComponents(target);
                send(getPage(), DEPTH, new AmountInputEvent(target));
            }

            @Override
            protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, RuntimeException e) {
                target.add(currencyTextField);
                target.focusComponent(currencyTextField);
            }
        });
        return currencyTextField;
    }
```

The test result is:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
mockNettViewController.updateAmount(<any>);
-> at uk.co.cdl.strata.web.client.accounts.payment.PostUnderwriterTransactionPanelTest.shouldUseDefaultCaseForUpdatingAmount(PostUnderwriterTransactionPanelTest.java:430)
```

Comment: What exactly does not work ?

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't trigger the onUpdate event. I've updated the question now.

Comment: Maybe it goes into the `onError`?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It is hitting the onError.